# Is there something like docker cloud "autodestroy" for Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-cloud

I am looking for a way to destroy a single shot container after exiting with success (0).

The docker cloud has an option called "autodestroy". Is there anything like that for Docker Swarm?

### Update

I would like to autoremove a successfully exited container in a Docker Swarm by adding "special information" to the compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no, that feature does not exist. If you were more descriptive about what you're looking to do, we might provide a better answer :)